# A question on elementary plane geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given a triangle $ABC$, let $S$ be an inner point of this triangle. Let $P$, $Q$, $R$ be the orthogonal projection of $S$ respectively on the three sides of this triangle. Are there beautiful methods (those which involve geometric insight with the least calculation) to find out the maximum among all $S$ of the product of non oriented lenghts $SP$, $SQ$, and $SR$?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the maximum among all $S$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for asking!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the $S$ that maximizes the product ought to be the intersection of the medians. But my derivation of that involves a bit of algebra and rudimentary calculus -- as well as some diagrams that I cannot reproduce in an answer right now.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking (well, actually I thought the answer would be the, equivalent, center of the inscribed circle).

Comment: @Lord_Farin: No, the center of the inscribed circle is the intersection of the _angle bisectors_, which is not usually the same as the intersection of the medians.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: To see that the center if the inscribed circle doesn't work, consider a very narrow isosceles triangle (with base angles very close to right). The inscribed circle has a center very close to the short side, but if you start S there and move towards the apex, the distance to the short side can easily double with hardly any corresponding decrease in the two other distances -- so their product will also become larger at the beginning of that movement.

Comment: Thank you @HenningMakholm for pointing that out; I apologise for my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you'd consider this as an algebraic or geometric solution.

$$SP \cdot AB = 2\mbox{Area} (SAB)$$
and similarly the other two.

Thus

$$SP \cdot SQ \cdot SR = 8 \frac{ \mbox{Area} (SAB) \mbox{Area} (SBC) \mbox{Area} (SAC)}{AB \cdot BC \cdot AC }$$

Hence, the product is maximal if the product $\mbox{Area} (SAB) \mbox{Area} (SBC) \mbox{Area} (SAC)$ is maximal. Maximizing thsi product is very easy with some algebra:

$$\sqrt[3]{\mbox{Area} (SAB) \mbox{Area} (SBC) \mbox{Area} (SAC)} \leq \frac{ \mbox{Area} (SAB) + \mbox{Area} (SBC) + \mbox{Area} (SAC)}{3}=  \frac{ \mbox{Area} (ABC) }{3}$$

with equality if and only if $\mbox{Area} (SAB) = \mbox{Area} (SBC) = \mbox{Area} (SAC)$. Thus the maximum is obtained when

$$\mbox{Area} (SAB) =\mbox{Area} (SBC)= \mbox{Area} (SAC)$$

It is easy to conclude that $S=G$ .

Comment: Thank you, this is the kind of solution that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partially geometric solution. For brevity let's write $x$, $y$, $z$ for the distances $SP$, $SQ$, $SR$, and $b$, $a$, $c$ for the corresponding side lengths, as in the following diagram. Furthermore, let $h$ be the length of altitude $CH$, parallel to the line $z$:

[image: diagram referred to in text]

We want to find an $S$ that maximizes $xyz$.

From **calculus** we know that if $S$ is at a local extremum at we move it an infinitesimal distance in *any* direction, $xyz$ must not change (to first order). In particular, this must be true if we imagine moving $S$ a small distance $\varepsilon$ to the left (away from point $F$ in the diagram). When we do so, $x$ increases and $y$ decreases, but since we're moving $S$ *horizontally*, $z$ stays the same.

Because triangles $HAC$ and $PFS$ are similar we can compute the increase in $x$ as $\Delta x = \varepsilon h/b$. Mutatis mutandis we find $\Delta y = -\varepsilon h/a$ (with the opposite sign because an increase in $x$ corresponds to a decreas in $y$).

A bit of simple **algebra** now gives
$$ \Delta\, xyz = (x+\Delta x)(y+\Delta y)z - xyz = \frac{\varepsilon hyz}b - \frac{\varepsilon hxz}{a} + \text{terms involving }\varepsilon^2$$

Because $\varepsilon$ is small we can ignore the $\varepsilon^2$ term. Since $\Delta xyz$ must be $0$ we then have
$$ \frac{\varepsilon hyz}b = \frac{\varepsilon hxz}a$$
Canceling common factors (all nonzero, since $z>0$ inside the triangle) and cross-multiplying gives us
$$ \tag{1} ya = xb $$
which we recognize as the equation of a line in the $x,y$ coordinate system. (This coordinate system is not rectangular, but equations of lines look the same in skew coordinates). If we can find two different solutions to $(1)$, the line connecting them will be a locus that every local extremum of $xyz$ inside the triangle must lie on.

The corner $C$ is is clearly a solution to $(1)$ because there we have $x=y=0$. Where can we find another one? The *midpoint* between $A$ and $B$ must be one, because there both sides of $(1)$ happen to be the area of triangle $ABC$.

So every local extremum of $xyz$ must lie on the median from $C$, and repeating the argument with another orientation we can see that it must lie on the other medians too. So the *intersection of the medians* is the only place in the inside of a triangle that can be a local extremum.

Since there quite obviously must be a *global maximum* somewhere in the triangle, the intersection of the medians has to be it.